# IE doesn't render <div> element if its left and width are large numbers

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I saw a strange rendering issue in IE.
When I set left of an element to a large negative value and width to a large positive value, IE (10) doesn't render the element at all, even though the element should be partial visible. I tried it in Firefox and it works fine. Part of the element is shown in Firefox.

My question is why it happens and what's the work around?

Below is the code to reproduce it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div style="background-color:red;height:24px;left:-1833184px;width:3509490px;position:absolute;border-style:solid;border-color:blue;border-width:1px"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What could possibly be 1.8m pixels left and 3.5m pixels wide?

Comment: In a timeline. The timeline can zoom in to nanosecond and the data can span a few seconds. After the timeline is zoomed in, the element representing the data can be that large.

Answer (score 2):

IE max px values are 1342177.27px

Comment: Then everything that's larger than 1342177.27px doesn't work well?

Comment: I believe that doesn't cause the issue.